# Django trigger script inside multiple different popups

Tags: django

I am new to django and trying to run a script when a user clicks on a confirmation button located inside a popup. This button is located inside a table that contains various information, including an ID, which I would like to pass to the script.

Also, I don't want the script to reload a new page.

Here is the table in the `index.html` file

```
    {% for st in scrapestats %}
    <tr>
        <td class="text-left">{{st.market}}</td>
        <td>{{st.start|date:"Y-m-d H:i:s"}}</td>
        <td>{{st.end|date:"Y-m-d H:i:s"}}</td>
        <td>{{st.finished_count}}/{{st.total_count}}</td>
        <td><a href="#"><span class="badge">{{st.ads}}</span></a></td>
        <td><a href="#"><span class="badge">{{st.ads_feedback}}</span></a></td>
        <td><a href="#"><span class="badge">{{st.user}}</span></a></td>
        <td><a href="#"><span class="badge">{{st.seller_feedback}}</span></a></td>

        <td><button type="button" name={{st.process_id}} class="btn btn-danger btn-xs confirm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal-{{st.process_id}}">
                Revert
            </button>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="Modal-{{st.process_id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title" align='left' id="delete-server-{{st.process_id}}">Are you sure you want to delete process id {{st.process_id}} ?</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body" align='left'>
                    This might be dangerous !
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <!-- <form action="#" method="POST" id="call_delete_server"> -->
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="button" id="confirm_deletion" data-id={{st.process_id}} class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                    <!-- </form> -->
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

And the script, also in the `index.html`

```
<script>
    $("#confirm_deletion").click(function (e) {
        console.log($(this).attr("data-id"));
        });
</script>
```

What happens is that when I click on the last button in the `{% for st in scrapestats %}` loop, it correctly outputs the id, but on any of the other buttons, it doesn't output anything.

Comment: `id` values should be unique in the HTML document.  
In your example, all buttons use the same id "confirm_deletion". And that may explain your problem.

For example you could use a specific class, instead of an id, to select all buttons in the script.

Comment: Thanks, it now works.